# Setter for nested interface

Tags: java

I didn't manage to compile a set of classes with nested interfaces.

Let's assume there are two interfaces:

```
public interface IntA
{   
    public Map<String, ? extends IntB> getName();
    public void setName(Map<String, ? extends IntB> name);
}

public interface IntB
{
    long getId();
    void setId(long id);
}
```

and two corresponding implementation classes

```
public class ImplA implements IntA,Serializable
{
    private Map<String, ImplB> name;
    public Map<String, ? extends IntB> getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(Map<String, ? extends IntB> name)
                  {this.name = (Map<String, ImplB>)name;}
}

public class ImplB implements IntB,Serializable
{
    private long id;
    public long getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}
}
```

How can i use the setter of ImplA?

```
public static void create(Random rnd, String code)
{
  ImplB b = new ImplB();
  b.setId(1);

  ImplA a = new ImplA();
  a.getName().put("key", b);
  a.getName().put("key", (IntB)b);
}
```

results in:

```
put(java.lang.String,capture#50 of ? extends IntB) in
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,capture#50 of ? extends .IntB>
cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,ImplB)

put(java.lang.String,capture#845 of ? extends IntB) in
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,capture#845 of ? extends IntB>
cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,IntB)
```

Thank you

Thor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getter is returning a more general type. Imagine if it the actual return value was a reference to a `Map<String, SomeOtherImplB>` - you wouldn't want to be able to put an `ImplB` there.

If you want to be able to put a value into a `Map`, you either need the value type to be specified exactly, or specified with a "super" constraint rather than an "extends" constraint. For example:

```
// This is fine
Map<String, ? super Apple> map = getMapFromSomewhere();
map.put("Foo", new Apple());

// This isn't - it might be a Map<String, Orange>!
Map<String, ? extends Fruit> map = getMapFromSomewhere();
map.put("Foo", new Apple());
```

So that's why it's not working at the moment. As for the right way to work around that... it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do. *Maybe* you want to change it to:

```
public interface IntA
{   
    public Map<String, IntB> getName();
    public void setName(Map<String, IntB> name);
}
```

... or the alternative is to make `IntA` generic:

```
public interface IntA<T extends IntB> 
{   
    public Map<String, T> getName();
    public void setName(Map<String, T> name);
}
```

So in this case, your `ImplA` class would implement `IntA<ImplB>`.

Comment: Dear Jon. Thank you for the quick reply. At the end of the day I'm targeting a utility class helping me in different projects. I want something like you first suggestion, but the implementing class ImplA should not have a variable (private Map<String, IntB> name;), it must have the concrete class as a variable (private Map<String, ImplB> name;), because it's a @Entity. ImplA will always deal with the same implementation of IntB (Apples).

Comment: @Thor: Then that suggests you should make the interface generic. There's no other way round it (while maintaining type safety).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know in which way. public interface IntA<T extends IntB> is not what I want. IntA should not extend IntB, IntA should have a Map<String,IntB>.

Comment: @Thor: `IntA` *doesn't* extend `IntB` - it has a *type parameter* which extends `IntB`. And you've said explicitly that `IntA` *shouldn't* have a `Map<String, IntB>` - because that's not the same as a `Map<String, Foo>` where `Foo` is a type extending `IntB`.

Comment: I got it! (and it's working) :-) Thank you so much Jon, I've definitively learned about a new piece of Java coding.